# How to make a function to wait for a specific time in Windows phone?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7.1, sleep, thread-sleep

I am building a Windows phone application with lots of animations. What I need is that when the application starts, it should be done finishing the first animation, say myS() is the name of the storyboard. Only after it is done with the animation, a textblock should appear after 3 seconds. What methods should I use to make the display of textbox wait for the Storyboard to finish? 
What I tried is using Thread.Sleeps(10000) but that doesn't work. This is the code -

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        c1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; //c1 is the name of the textbox
        myS.Begin();
        canDisp();
    }

    private void e1_ManipulationStarted(object sender, ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
    {
        myS1.Begin();
    }

    private void e1_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        myS2.Begin();
    }
    void canDisp()
    {
        c1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }}
```

After the myS.Begin() is done executing, I want the program to wait for 3 seconds & then execute the canDisp() method, how can I achieve that?

Comment: have you tried anything yet?

Comment: when it ends, start a timer, when the timer ticks at 3 seconds, do that thing

Comment: @Jason, yes I've tried placing the Thread.Sleeps(3000) just below myS.Begin(), what it did was delay the opening of application by 3000 units.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your animation is a `Storyboard` then it has a `Completed` event ([MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.completed%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)) for just this purpose.

Your call to `Thread.Sleep()` was probably being run on the same thread as the animation and so was stopping the animation from running while it was sleeping.
If you really want to go down this route then you'll need to move your sleep call to a different thread.

---

If you really want to use threads, a simple way to do it is:

```
System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(obj =>
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show("after delay");
            });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, can you please give an example? How do you move a sleep call to a different thread?

Comment: don't use the completed event. It's much simpler.

Comment: I used the completed event, it worked! Thank you!
Although I'd like to know how to move a sleep call to a different thread.

Comment: @Sidsec9 Glad to help. The way to show appreciation here is to accept the answer and upvote as appropriate.

Comment: System.Threading.Thread && System.Threading.ThreadPool are both unavailable in a Portable Class Library.

Comment: @ZackWeiner that's true. But it has nothing to do with this question. Similarly, MessageBox, StoryBoard, PhoneApplicationPage, Visibility and manipulation events also can't be used in a PCL. What's your point?

Comment: @MattLacey A storyboard can be used in Win8, WinRT, WinPhone7 or WinPhone8 so an agnostic solution to the problem using a ManualResetEvent instead of Thread.Sleep() would allow use of the same code base to solve the same problem on all platforms without needing to copy the code into each project.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a windows store app where System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem
is not available.So I did like this and not working as expected

```
  await Windows.System.Threading.ThreadPool.RunAsync(async (s) =>
        {

            await Task.Delay(1);
            await MainViewModel.Instance.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.High, () =>
            {
            MessageBox.Show("after delay");
             });
             }, Windows.System.Threading.WorkItemPriority.High);
```

Comment: @Sidsec9@MattLacey@ZackWeine

Comment: @MattLacey How above code works in Windows 8.1 store app.